# SQL script to drop indexes for specific columns in a dimension in Oracle

Tags: oracle, indexing, data-warehouse, dimensions

Supposing If i have created indexes for a set of attributes in one or more dimensions. How can i create a SQL script to drop the indexes.

Example: If i had

```
               index1 created for (Attribute1,Attribute2) of Dimension1
               index2 -> (Attribute3,Attribute4) of Dimension2
               index3 -> (Attribute5,Attribute6) of Dimension3
               ...          ..........              ...
               indexn -> (Attribute2,Attribute3) of Dimensionn
```

Now how to drop the index1, index2---indexn? Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure you want to drop them, or just disable them for loads then rebuild them afterwards?

Comment: I'm pretty sure i want to drop them..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use something like this, in a anonymous PL/SQL block:

```
FOR x IN ( SELECT 'drop index ' || index_name stmt
              FROM all_indexes
              where upper(index_name) like ('INDEX%'))
            LOOP
                    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE x.stmt;
            END LOOP;
```